# why is command line paste and enter not working in cloud9

Tags: command-line, paste, cloud9-ide, enter

I am working from Cloud9 IDE.  I've been cutting and pasting all afternoon.  All of a sudden I can not paste into the command window, or even enter a single character.  Does anyone know what could start this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to start another terminal and if it doesn't work, shutdown the workspace and reopen it.

Comment: That worked!  Don't know why, but I'll take it.  Working from new terminal now.  Thanks!!